# Increase product qty to more than 8 charcters

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently when I enter
9999999999999 (13 digits) in the Product Inventory tab of the admin, it automatically changes the qty to 99999999.9999 (8 floats and 4 decimals).

How can this be changed to allow the 13 non-decimal numerals?

Comment: What is your purpose behind it? Is it for selling item infinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: changing the value of the inventory datatype will lead to, at best frustration, and at worst unexpected behavior.

---

### How to do it

There's no magic query I can give you. You'll have to do some discovery on this. But here's what's at stake:

- The field that governs this size is called `qty` in the table `cataloginventory_stock_item`
- There are many types of quantities that are similar to this, though, including `max_sale_qty` and `min_qty`

  - In short, you'd have to change *all of them*.
- Beyond that you also have to consider the stock index tables, which have many values such as `min_qty`
- The DB itself may be capable of handling larger values but PHP itself has a float value that conforms to IEEE 64-bit format (ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). You may have issues with precision or run up against the limit.

### Why you probably don't want to

The obvious answer may be because tracking quantity of > 1 Zillion of an item is probably fruitless unless people are buying them in large quantities and you don't sell them in singles.

In that case you would reinterpret the value as the lowest "step" value, e.g. if you only sell in lots of 1000 you could easily trim 3 decimal places; so you interpret a qty 1 as qty 1000 in real life.

In MySQL you won't have an issue storing up to `DECIMAL(20,4)`, but you could have issues with PHP itself in Magento CE or even the stored procedures that affect reindexing in MySQL in Magento EE.

In short, I would suggest you rethink your approach.

Comment: I think he wants to sell items infinitely, so might be a better option just to set inventory management flag to "No", so he does not need to enter manually this value.

Comment: @IvanChepurnyi regardless it's an interesting question, but yes this is likely the goal. TBQH 99999999 is probably a serviceable number as well, seeing as it's larger than the number of iPhones ever sold.